# How to Parce list of Any type in kotlin using Parcelize?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I need to parce List of type Any in kotlin, How can I pass that?

Ex:

```
@Parcelize
data class Abc(
    val listOfAny: List<Any>,
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: You can't, because there may be elements in the list that are not primitives or Parcelables. If you can guarantee that all elements are primitive or Parcelable, you can manually write a Parcelable implementation instead of using Parcelize, and when you read/write objects of the list you can precede items with some value that indicates their type.